# What kind of graphic is the MacOS storage breakdown?

Tags: graphs

MacOS can display a concise, linear graph showing what percentage of disk is used and the relative amount of different kinds of data.

What is the name for this kind of graph? I wouldn't call it a pie chart or a bar chart.

[image: storage space graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this referred to as a single stacked bar chart (without the axis indicators).

It's also been called a [segmented bar chart](https://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-a-segmented-bar-chart/).

Since there is not any single running process, its goal is understanding the distribution of storage, and displaying proportion. There's not any progress to speak of, just distribution.

Comment: Yep - https://www.google.com/search?q=segmented+bar+chart gives various images like what I showed.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it's a stacked bar chart. https://datavizproject.com/data-type/stacked-bar-chart/

The whole Dataviz Project site is a great resource on various data visualisation tools for future reference and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the name is: Progress Bar Chart

Comment: It's very similar to a progress bar, but a progress bar just has two categories, finished and not finished, right? Whereas this has a breakdown of 4 categories - data in of type a, b, c, and unused space.

Comment: It is a tricky one. I agree. I think the word combination between Progress bar and Bar chart it makes sense.

Comment: @NathanLong While it's true the example in your screenshot has four categories, the number of categories will vary. For example, on one of my Macs, it has eight categories. Just depends on the types of data users have stored on the drive. That said, this doesn't change the correct answers posted by Mike and Mikael - just pointing out that stacked bar charts can have any number of categories.